# @semantic-release/commit-analyzer - Analyze all commits even from other branches

Tags: git, semantic-release

My `.releaserc.yml` is

```
plugins:
  - "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer"

branches:
  - "master"
```

I have that git log

```
*   224400b (HEAD -> master) fix: merge-1
|\
| * a28d643 (dev) commit-3
| * d7b35be commit-2
| * ee711df commit-1
|/
* b2b696e .gitignore
* 970faff (origin/release, origin/master, origin/HEAD) initial commit
```

That is giving me

```
[12:44:27 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Start step "analyzeCommits" of plugin "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer"
[12:44:27 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  Analyzing commit: fix: merge-1
[12:44:27 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  The release type for the commit is patch
[12:44:27 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  Analyzing commit: commit-3
[12:44:27 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  The commit should not trigger a release
[12:44:27 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  Analyzing commit: commit-2
[12:44:27 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  The commit should not trigger a release
[12:44:27 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  Analyzing commit: commit-1
[12:44:27 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  The commit should not trigger a release
[12:44:27 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  Analyzing commit: .gitignore
[12:44:27 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  The commit should not trigger a release
[12:44:27 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  Analyzing commit: initial commit
[12:44:27 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  The commit should not trigger a release
[12:44:27 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  Analysis of 6 commits complete: patch release
[12:44:27 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Completed step "analyzeCommits" of plugin "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer"
```

I don't understand why the plugin is analyzing all the commits and not only the commits of the master branch ?

Comment: You mean commits `ee711df commit-1`, `d7b35be commit-2`, `a28d643 commit-3`? Those commits **are** on the branch `master` (reached from `master`). They're **also** on the branch `dev` but that should prevent nothing AFAIK.

Comment: Ok.  So the problem is coming from my misunderstood of git.  I don't understand why those 3 commits are on both master and dev branches.

Comment: **A**. You've merged the branches, they're now merged. The graph is not linear. **B**. The word "branch" means 3 related but slightly different things in Git: *1*) a name and a pointer to a commit, this is the tip/head of the branch; *2*) the DAG — directed acyclic graph of commits started from the head and pointing to their parents; a merge commit has multiple parents so the DAG branches and merges; branches in that sens are not linear. *3*) remote-tracking branches; uninteresting for this discussion; they're special kind of branches in sense *1*.

Comment: Thx phd.  Not easy to understand.  I'm going to dig a little more.

Comment: The graph in your question is exactly such a DAG, branched and merged. There're two commits having `b2b696e .gitignore` as the sole parent; this is branching. The commit `24400b fix: merge-1` has two parents; this is merging. The entire branch consists of such splits in the DAG from the head back to the 1st commit in the repository. (To avoid overcomplicating the comment I omit a notion that a repository could contain a forest — multiple independent branched trees not grown from the same 1st commit.)